# Production environment variable doesn't seem to be set

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular12

EDIT: I've now upgraded the project to ng13 and the problem persists.

I'm building an Angular <strike>12</strike> 13 app (originally generated in maybe version 8 or 9).
My build command is `ng build --configuration=production --output-hashing=all`

and I'm expecting to see `MYAPP` written in the browser console on app start, but doesn't appear. (In reality I want to do other things but console.log illustrates my problem)

Snippet below from `main.ts`

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  console.log("MYAPP");
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have `console.clear()` anywhere in your code?  If you add an 'else' and a `cosnole.log('MYAPP - NON-PRODUCTION')` in it, do you see that?  What do you see if you do `console.log('environment:', environment)` before your if?

Comment: Cant find any `console.clear` . I tried your tip with the else-statement and the app is still in dev mode apparently.

Comment: I did an ugly but quick workaround to my actual problem. If I have the energy I might create an issue in the angular repo later on, unless a working answer surfaces here

Comment: It works for me.   I take it you're importing from src/environments/environment, and you haven't changed your angular.json, and it still has 'fileReplacements' in your production configuration that changes it to src/environments/environment.prod.ts and that file still has 'production: true' and the nofmral environment.ts has 'production: false'?   Does that show when you console.log(environment)?

Comment: You say 'the app is still in dev mode apparently', but that could be a lot of things as mentioned in my last comment.    What *exactly* do you see with `console.log(environment)`?  Try adding a new setting to environment.ts and environment.prod.ts and make sure the new setting displays even in dev mode.

Comment: Sry for slow reply, haven't had time to work on this lately. I don't remember the exact wording but the point was that ´environment´ was set to ´dev´. When I have time I will try to set up a new angular project and likely that will work as aspected when switching between prod/dev. My guess is that something has broken during an angular upgrade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell angular how to change the environment

Add something like this in your angular .json in configurations production

```
"fileReplacements": [
                            {
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }
                        ],
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The build command flag `--configuration=production` is fairly new. If you are still using an older version of the Angular CLI (different from framework) you need to run `ng build --prod`

Comment: I switched away from —prod since the CLI showed a deprecated warning. So my version is probably recent enough